# Question about MVC folder structure

Tags: php, model-view-controller

To use the MVC pattern/layout structure, does it basicly require everything to be loaded through 1 file, like your index file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The MVC pattern only dictates a separation of concerns regarding event/request handling, data modelling and user interface. The way this is implemented is not specified.

Many (all?) of the current PHP frameworks I am aware of *do* use a single entry point (index.php) and route from there. This often makes use of the "Front Controller" pattern.

The other method (using a separate PHP file per page) is known as the Page Controller pattern. It has the advantage of being much simpler, but loses the application wide control afforded by the front controller and may be prone to code duplication.

Comment: I believe my current setup may be similar to the "Page Controller" you mention, I have an includes folder with header, footer, bootstrap, and all class files in it, then each section of my site has it's own folder and set of pages that include the appropriate files

Answer (score 1):

No. Nothing about the MVC pattern in and of itself says anything about how your files or folders should be arranged. A given framework that you use might mandate a particular arrangement, however.